# The request object does not contain the required `authentication` attribute when trying to API login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to skip CSRF token required middleware for API prefix , Here I'm using cakephp authentication plugin 2.x. I have tried below code to avoid token for api prefix

```
public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
{
            $middlewareQueue->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(Configure::read('Error')))
            $csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware();
               
            $csrf->skipCheckCallback(function ($request) {
                    // Skip token check for API URLs.
                    if ($request->getParam('prefix') === 'Api') {
                        return true;
                    }
            });
                
           // add Authentication after RoutingMiddleware
           $middlewareQueue->add($csrf);
}


public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => Router::url('/login'),
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

        // Load identifiers, ensure we check email and password fields

        $identifierSettings = [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
        ];

        $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', $identifierSettings);

        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
        
        // Configure form data check to pick email and password
        $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
            // 'loginUrl' => Router::url('/admin'),
        ]);

        return $authenticationService;
    }
```

I have written below controller login action for login

```
public function login()
    {
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();

        if($result->isValid())
        {
            $user = $result->getData();
            $this->set('user',$user);
            $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', 'user');
        }
    }
```

Agter send request using postman , I have got below response

[image]

I have nothing set in authentication option in postman, Do I need anything to set in postman ? What is this authentication attribute ?

Comment: The `authentication` attribute holds an instance of the authentication service, giving access to the authenticated identity, etc. This is being set by the authentication middleware, which I do not see being loaded in your `middleware()` code!?

Comment: @ndm I have updated with getAuthenticationService interface method.

Comment: That method alone won't do anything, you still need to [**load the authentication middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html#getting-started), which will then obtain the service via the `getAuthenticationService()` method.